# no display fail message from controller

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I need validate user's nickname when the gonna registre in my proyect:

**My Controller**

```
$inputData = Input::get('nickname');
        parse_str($inputData); 
        $informacion = array('nickname' => $inputData);
        $regla = array('nickname'=>'required|unique:usuarios|alpha_num|min:6|max:15');
    if($request->ajax()){
        $usuarios = Usuarios::Usuarios();

        $validar = Validator::make($informacion,$regla);
        if($validar->fails()){
            return Response()->json(array(
            'fail' => true,
            'errors' => $validar->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        }
        else{
           return Response()->json(array('success' => true, "message" => "Nombre de Usuario Disponible"));
        }
    }
```

**My Script**

```
$( "#validar" ).click(function( event ) {
  var dato = $('#nickname').val();
  var route = $('#form-sign-up').attr('action');
  var tipo = $('#form-sign-up').attr('method');
  var token = $('#form-sign-up #token').val();
  $.ajax({
      url: route,
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
      type: tipo,
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{nickname: dato},})


        .fail(function(data){
          $('#nickname-msj').html(data.errors);
          $('#nickname-msj').fadeIn();
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#nickname-msj').html(data.message);
            $('#nickname-msj').fadeIn();
        });
});
```

.done works, but .fails not, and i need display that information to my user, because so they can know what is the problem, if someone can help me will be great.

I am using Laravel 5.2

Thank you.

Comment: You could use the `google chrome inspector` and head to the network tab and submit your form you will get the response regarding the form.

Answer (score 0):

The fails function of Ajax is triggered with a code different from `200`. So you can return

```
if($validar->fails()) { 
    return response()->json($arrayHere, 400); //HTTP 400 error for bad request
}
```

So, just basically add `400` after your array, inside of `json()` function. When you don't specify the code, it defaults to `200`.

Maybe also change your ajax request ? Or not

```
$.ajax({

        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: tipo,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
             nickname: dato
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```